# SQL: INSERT INTO...VALUES..SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

How do i write INSERT statement if i get the values of colA from TableX, colB from TableY and colC from TableZ?

eg: INSERT INTO TableA (colA, colB, colC) VALUES (?,?,?)

Any ideas if it is possible?

Comment: is this Java? seams to be a simple SQL problem, or did I miss something?

Comment: Java tag seems to be added by accident, I'll see if I can remove it

Answer (score 40):

```
INSERT INTO TableA(colA, colB, colC)
  SELECT TableX.valA, TableY.valB, TableZ.valC
    FROM TableX
   INNER JOIN TableY ON :......
   INNER JOIN TableZ ON ........
```

Of course, TableX, TableY and TAbleZ might also be related in some other way (not INNER JOIN).

If you cannot find any relation between the tables AT ALL, you could also do three separate

```
SELECT @value1 = valA FROM TableX WHERE ......
SELECT @value2 = valB FROM TableY WHERE ......
SELECT @value3 = valC FROM TableZ WHERE ......
```

and then an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(colA, colB, colC)
             VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3)
```

That's the ultimate last resort, you can can't express everything in a single `SELECT` statement.

Marc

Answer (score 24):

In response to marc_s's answer, you can query from unrelated tables in a since select like:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
    (colA, colB, colC)
SELECT
    (SELECT valA FROM TableX WHERE ...),
    (SELECT valB FROM TableY WHERE ...),
    (SELECT valC FROM TableZ WHERE ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Insert into TableA (ColA, ColB, ColC) . . .
```

Must be the column names as the are in Table A.
There's nothing wrong with

```
Insert into TableA (ColA, ColB, ColC) . . .
Select TableX.Col1, TableY.Col1, TableZ.Col5 
From TableX, TableY, TableZ
Where . . .
```

Comment: ok..great...i'm using this in java, so if colC is getting the values frm a method (eg: method())?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join the tables that you want to make the selection from.

Here is a resource on SQL joins:

[www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

You also might want to check out this free PDF book from the guys at [www.simple-talk.com](http://www.simple-talk.com/) that covers SQL basics:

[SQL Server Crib Sheet Compendium](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/free-ebook-sql-server-crib-sheet-compendium/)