# Declare temporary procedure variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am following this post: [SQL: INSERT INTO...VALUES..SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856707/sql-insert-into-values-select)

and my qustion is how do I declare the temporary @value1 which is assigned a value from a SELECT statement? I have something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE name
(
@arg1 as type1,
@arg2 as type2
)

AS
    @value1 = SELECT x from tabley WHERE <something>

    INSERT INTO Table(x,y,z) VALUES(@arg1,@arg2,@value1)
```

but I dont know where to declare and set @value1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE name
(
@arg1 as type1,
@arg2 as type2
)

AS
DECLARE @value1 as type1

     SELECT @value1=x from tabley WHERE <something>

    INSERT INTO Table(x,y,z) VALUES(@arg1,@arg2,@value1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @value1 := x from tabley WHERE <something>
```

Answer (score 0):

`DECLARE @value1 as type = (SELECT ...)`
in place of you statement