# insert row into the table from values in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to insert the row in table. but the problem is how to get values from two different tables tables.

`ITABLE` has three Columns `( StudentPhoto , StudentName , StudentID )`

`DTABLE` has `(StudentPhoto , StudentID )`

`LTABLE` have `(StudentName, StudentID)`

I want to insert the data into Table `ITABLE` from Table `DTABLE` and `LTABLE`.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: INSERT INTO...VALUES..SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856707/sql-insert-into-values-select)

Comment: Does DTable and LTable has StudentID as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this

```
insert into ITABLE (StudentPhoto , StudentName , StudentID)
SELECT d.StudentPhoto,l.StudentName,d.StudentID
FROM DTABLE d
INNER JOIN l  LTABLE ON d.StudentID= l.StudentID
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have Studentid in Ltable..you can't made a join.Isn't it?